# How to create radio group of a real buttons?

Tags: android, button, radio-button

I'd like to create a button group of a "real" buttons?
I'd like to display to user buttons which contains his attending option: Yes, No and Meybe.
I'd like to use buttons for this display.
How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a selector xml file in drawable folder

checkbox_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_active" />
      <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_inactive" />
</selector>
```

And apply this background to your radio buttons

```
 <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" />
```